# Switch/alert browser tab with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

I have a warning which users need to respond to on my site. Ideally I'd like to switch their tab in a similar way to how the alert() function currently does but without the alert popup.

If this isn't possible is there any way to make the tab flash to show a user response is needed?

Comment: Good question but is there a reason you can't/don't want to use an alert? They seem ideal for what you want to do.

Comment: *"Ideally I'd like to switch their tab in a similar way to how the alert() function currently does but without the alert popup."* It appals me to discover that `alert` does that on otherwise-decent browsers (tested on current Chrome and Firefox; yikes). A page shouldn't try to grab the tab like that. The *user* should be in control. Just show your message on the page (using something styled and modern, not `alert`); if the user's using your page, they'll see it. It's *their* choice.

Comment: You might consider [notifications](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) ([here's an article](http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications)).

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I already have a modal that pops up with some inputs on. The alert would be redundant and doesn't have the functionality to completely replace my modal popup.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 

"if the user's using your page, they'll see it. It's their choice." I agree with what you're saying. However, this is for a product that CSRs will be using at the company I work for. They're not using anything but this product, they just often have other tabs open to the same product and sometimes miss warning popups from other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to not spam the users watching your page/on your tab but work with your flow is this.

### JavasScript

```
Function WarnUser ()
{
    //If user isn't on this page alert them to problem.
    if (!document.hasFocus()) 
    {
        alert("Warning!");
    }

    //Create pop up to deal with warning
}
```

I know this uses an `Alert` but your dialog would resolve the issue, the alert just brings them to the tab having a problem. Also with `!document.hasFocus()` it would only alert them when they are somewhere else which removes some of the redundancy.

Alternatively if a `prompt` dialog could resolve your warning that would also have a similar affect.